# Flutter Firebase - Stream to listen if user has been disabled / deleted

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter

Below is my simple streambuilder code to listen for auth event changes using AuthStateListener when the user logs in/out.

Essentially would to have the same realtime update when the firebase user has been disabled / deleted in the firebase console so that the user can be logged off from the app.

```
 return StreamBuilder<String>(
    stream: auth.onAuthStateChanged,
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
        final bool isLoggedIn = snapshot.hasData; 
        if (isLoggedIn) {              
          return MainPage();                      
        } else {              
          return LoginPage();
```

Comment: I didn't get what you want to achieve, can you explain further

Comment: Hi, using the above code, it is possible to listen for realtime updates when the user signs-in/out of the app realtime. In the case when the user has logged into the app and this user has been disabled from the Firebase Auth console, is there any stream to listen to this event so that the user can be logged out from the app.

Comment: Cannot flag as duplicate, but there is an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64769396/13876163).