# FirebaseAuth Disabled Users check and signout?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

so i am having a stream of onAuthStateChanged and i want check if the user has been disabled by the administrator on firebase console to logout the user and go to login page again , here is my stream checking if the user is loged or not , but how to check if the user disabled by firebase console :\
here is a simple code of my stream :

```
    return StreamBuilder<FirebaseUser>(
      stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
      builder: (BuildContext context , snapshot){


        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
              FirebaseUser user = snapshot.data;
              if (user == null) {
                return RegisterUi();
              }
              ;
            } else {
return HomePage()
    }

    }
    );
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged` is deprecated.
You should use either `authStateChanges` or `userChanges`.

Unfortunately none of them emits values when the user gets disabled.

You can attempt to reload the user data with

```dart
FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.reload();
```

If the user is disabled, it will throw a `FirebaseAuthException e` where
`e.code` is `'user-disabled'`.

Some untested code:

```dart
try {
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.reload();
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'user-disabled') {
         // User is disabled.
      }
    }
```

In your example, if you `reload()`, the stream will emit `null` and the `RegisterUi()` widget will be returned from the builder.